# Where can I get the Power BI Dashboard in a Day data

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, powerbi-datasource

There is a in depth tutorial that leads you through building a dashboard. I can't get started because the first thing is to connect to a cloud resource that doesn't(?) exist.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the files [here](https://github.com/joegravelyn/PowerBI_DIAD).

Two notes about these files:

1) These are from June and might be outdated if you are looking at newer instructions.

2) To get around GitHub's size cap, I had to break a couple of .csv files up:

- AU Sales.csv, which should have no effect on following along with the instructions.
- bi_salesFact.csv, which will cause you to treat the US Sales data like the international data by importing it using the folder option instead of the file option